# Joining two tables and displaying the count of records based on country in Northwind schema

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, i have two tables - Supplier and customer. Each has a field name 'Country'
 I have to find the total number of suppliers and customers by Country and then add these two counts to display as a single count for each country.

I have two queries, one for each table(supplier and customer). But how to combine them?

```
SELECT S.Country, count(distinct(S.CompanyName)) as cnt
from NW_Suppliers S
group by S.Country

SELECT C.Country, count(distinct(C.CustomerID)) as cnt1
from NW_Customers C
group by C.Country
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What do you want to do when you combine the two? Add the counts, show both counts, something else?

Comment: Add counts. For example:  if Venezuela had 3 suppliers and 4 customers, it would be listed as count =  7

Comment: Also `DISTINCT` is a keyword not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the two together:

```
SELECT COALESCE( S.Country, C.Country ) AS country,
       COALESCE( c.cnt, 0 ) + COALESCE( s.cnt, 0 ) AS total
FROM   ( SELECT   Country,
                  COUNT( DISTINCT CompanyName ) AS cnt
         FROM     NW_Suppliers
         GROUP BY Country
       ) S
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT   Country,
                  COUNT( DISTINCT CustomerID ) AS cnt
         FROM     NW_Customers
         GROUP BY Country
       ) C
       ON ( s.country = c.country )
```

Or `UNION` the two tables:

```
SELECT Country,
       COUNT( DISTINCT name ) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT Country, CompanyName AS Name
  FROM   NW_Suppliers
  UNION
  SELECT Country, CustomerID
  FROM   NW_Customers
)
GROUP BY Country
```

They will give slightly different answers depending on how you want to treat duplicates between the two tables but its unclear from your description what your intended behaviour should be.

Comment: Both works fine!. Thanks a lot :)
I just added 'group by' in 2nd query

Comment: A literal interpretation of the OP's post (although it may not be his/her true requirement) would be to SELECT DISTINCT countries in the two branches of the union, but then to UNION ALL the two results. That way, if a company is a duplicate either as a customer or as a supplier, that is counted only once (for each capacity), but if a company is both a customer and a supplier, it is counted twice - once for each capacity. Again, maybe that is not what's needed, but it is what the OP's words mean (whether intentionally or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.Country, count(distinct(S.CompanyName)) as cnt
from NW_Suppliers S
group by S.Country

Union all

SELECT C.Country, count(distinct(C.CustomerID)) as cnt
from NW_Customers C
group by C.Country
```